# Calculating r(t) with line integrals

Tags: calculus, integration

I have $F(x,y)$ equalling some $a \mathrm{i}+b\mathrm{j}+c\mathrm{k}$ is that all $r(t)$ is?

What if all of $a,b,c$ are not in terms of $t$?

> Note: My $F(x,y)$ is a vector field.

Or does it come from my $C$ where $C$ is a rectangle?

Example: Vector field: $F(x,y) = x^2 y^2 \;\mathrm{i} + x \;\mathrm{j}$. Let $C$ be a rectangle with vertices $(0,0),(4,0),(4,4),(0,4)$ , let $T$ denote the unit tangent vector $C$ directed anti clockwise around $C$

I want $T$, which I know requires $r(t)$

Comment: From $C$ you will get the limits of integration and parametrize the curve.

Comment: Without an example of the line integral you are trying to compute (so that we know how $F(x,y)$, $r(t)$, and $C$ are used), it is hard to answer this question.

Comment: I'm assuming your line integral should be $\int_C \vec{F} \circ d\vec{r}$.  Your $\vec{r}(t)$ will come from parameterizing a path along the rectangle (i.e. $C$).

Comment: @Jared Will I have to have $\sum_{n=1}^4 C_n$ paths parameterized because it is a rectangle, and does that imply 4 different $r(t)$?

Comment: @user142198 Basically yes.  I wouldn't necessarily say that you have $4$ different $\vec{r}(t)$'s rather four integrals, each representing different sections of the curve.  _Although_ technically you can choose a parameterization such that all of the integrals are from $0$ to $1$ (or $0$ to $4$, or $a$ to $b$) which means you could write it as a single integral (but you'll still have to add up the different $\vec{r}(t)$'s for each section).

Comment: @Jared how would one merge the 4 sections into one integral? 

Are you saying I could take $r(t)= 3t \mathrm{i}, 0 \mathrm{j}, 0 \leq t \leq 1, r(t) =3 \mathrm{i}, t-1 \mathrm{j}, 1 \leq t \leq 2$ and merge them into one $r(t)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parameterize the four legs of the rectangle as follows:

\begin{align}
\vec{r}_1(t) =& (t, 0) & 0 \leq t \leq 4\\
\vec{r}_2(t) = & (4, t) & 0 \leq t \leq 4 \\
\vec{r}_3(t) = & (4 - t, 4) & 0 \leq t \leq 4 \\
\vec{r}_4(t) = & (0, 4 - t) & 0 \leq t \leq 4
\end{align}

But don't forget that you need to plug in each of those values into $\vec{F}$:

$$
\int\limits_0^4 \vec{F}\left(\vec{r}_1\right)\circ d\vec{r}_1 + \int\limits_0^4 \vec{F}\left(\vec{r}_2\right)\circ d\vec{r}_2 + \int\limits_0^4 \vec{F}\left(\vec{r}_3\right)\circ d\vec{r}_3 + \int\limits_0^4 \vec{F}\left(\vec{r}_4\right)\circ d\vec{r}_4
$$

You can combine this into a single integral, but you still need to evaluate each $\vec{F}\left(r_i\right)\circ d\vec{r}_i$.  For example, here is $\vec{r}_1$:

$$
x = t, y = 0\\
d\vec{r}_1 = \left(1, 0\right)dt \\
\vec{F}\left(\vec{r}_1\right) = \left(t^2\cdot 0^2, t\right) = \left(0, t\right) \\
\vec{F}\left(\vec{r}_1\right) \circ d\vec{r}_1 = 0 dt
$$

Now you need to do the same for the other three.  You can probably guess that it will vanish again for $\vec{r}_4$, but it probably won't for the other two.

Comment: One final question: If I were to use each of the $r(t)$ valued as calculated above and take them to $v(t)$ using $v(t) = r'(t)$ and then to $T(t)$ using $T(t) = \frac{v(t)}{||v(t)||}$. Then using these I can calculate $\oint_C \mathrm{F}.\mathrm{T} \; \mathrm{ds}$ adding together each of the integrals using each $T$ for a total of four $\oint$s? Wow sorry this was a long question, I hope it makes sense!

Comment: Well, the way I parameterized the rectangle I automatically have that $d\vec{r}_i$ is a unit vector.